# Unit Test: SMTP mock server, for testing SMTP send email

Tags: go, mocking, smtp

I have test email logic, to send email, that is working fine.

Now to unit test that, I copied mock SMTP server code from https://golang.org/src/net/smtp/smtp_test.go, line 639 function => TestSendMailWithAuth

Mail code that works :

1. Types used

```
type Email struct {
    Subject      string
    Body         string
    TemplateFile string
    TemplateData interface{}
}

type pluginInput struct{
    SMTPServer            string        
    Username              string        
    Password              string        
    From                  string        
    To                    string        
    Cc                    string     
}

email := &Email{
                Subject:      "SendMail test",
                Body:         `<!DOCTYPE html>
                <html lang="en">
                <head>
                    <title>IDP Execution Summary Email</title>
                </head>
                <body>test email</body>
                </html>`,
            }
```

2. Code that sends email

```
func (email *Email) SendMail(pluginInput *PluginInput) error {

    // Connect to the remote SMTP server.
    smtpClient, err := smtp.Dial(pluginInput.SMTPServer)
    if err != nil {
        logger.Error(err)
        return err
    }

    //smtpServerHost
    smtpServerHost, _, err := net.SplitHostPort(pluginInput.SMTPServer)

    //start tls with no certificate check
    if ok, _ := smtpClient.Extension("STARTTLS"); ok {
        // #nosec G402
        config := &tls.Config{ServerName: smtpServerHost, InsecureSkipVerify: true}
        if err = smtpClient.StartTLS(config); err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }

    //set smtp client auth
    if ok, authMechanism := smtpClient.Extension("AUTH"); ok {
        userNameWithoutDomain := strings.Split(pluginInput.Username, "@")[0]
        switch authMechanism {
        case ``:
            err = smtpClient.Auth(nil)
        case `LOGIN`:
            err = smtpClient.Auth(LoginAuth(userNameWithoutDomain, pluginInput.Password))
        case `CRAM-MD5`:
            err = smtpClient.Auth(smtp.CRAMMD5Auth(userNameWithoutDomain, pluginInput.Password))
        case `PLAIN`:
            err = smtpClient.Auth(smtp.PlainAuth("", userNameWithoutDomain, pluginInput.Password, smtpServerHost))
        default:
            err = smtpClient.Auth(smtp.PlainAuth("", userNameWithoutDomain, pluginInput.Password, smtpServerHost))
        }
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }

    // From
    if err = smtpClient.Mail(pluginInput.Username); err != nil {
        logger.Error(err)
        return err
    }
    // To & Cc
    toArr := strings.Split(pluginInput.To, ",")
    ccArr := strings.Split(pluginInput.Cc, ",")
    toArr = append(toArr, ccArr...)
    for _, addr := range toArr {
        if err = smtpClient.Rcpt(addr); err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }

    //body
    msg := "To: " + pluginInput.To + "\r\n" +
        "Cc: " + pluginInput.Cc + "\r\n" +
        "Subject: " + email.Subject + "\r\n" +
        mIMEHeaders + "\r\n" + email.Body

    // send Data command tp smtp server
    smtpWriterCloser, err := smtpClient.Data()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    _, err = fmt.Fprintf(smtpWriterCloser, msg)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if err = smtpWriterCloser.Close(); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    //send Quit command to SMTP server
    if err = smtpClient.Quit(); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

3. Unit test code for this:

```
func TestEmail_SendMail(t *testing.T) {

    l, err := net.Listen("tcp", "127.0.0.1:0")
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("Unable to create listener: %v", err)
    }
    defer l.Close()

    errCh := make(chan error)
    go func() {
        defer close(errCh)
        conn, err := l.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            errCh <- fmt.Errorf("Accept: %v", err)
            return
        }
        defer conn.Close()

        tc := textproto.NewConn(conn)
        tc.PrintfLine("220 hello world")
        msg, err := tc.ReadLine()
        if err != nil {
            errCh <- fmt.Errorf("ReadLine error: %v", err)
            return
        }
        const wantMsg = "EHLO localhost"
        if msg != wantMsg {
            errCh <- fmt.Errorf("unexpected response %q; want %q", msg, wantMsg)
            return
        }
        err = tc.PrintfLine("250 mx.google.com at your service")
        if err != nil {
            errCh <- fmt.Errorf("PrintfLine: %v", err)
            return
        }
    }()

    type fields struct {
        Subject      string
        Body         string
        TemplateFile string
        TemplateData interface{}
    }
    type args struct {
        pluginInput *PluginInput
    }
    tests := []struct {
        name    string
        fields  fields
        args    args
        wantErr bool
    }{
        {
            name: "without tls email send testing",
            fields: fields{
                Subject: "SendMail test",
                Body: `<!DOCTYPE html>
                <html lang="en">
                <head>
                    <title>IDP Execution Summary Email</title>
                </head>
                <body>test email</body>
                </html>`,
            },
            args: args{&PluginInput{
                SMTPServer: l.Addr().String(),
                Username:   "test@example.com",
                To:         "other@example.com",
                Cc:         "another@example.com",
            }},
            wantErr: true,
        },
    }
    for _, tt := range tests {
        t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            email := &Email{
                Subject:      tt.fields.Subject,
                Body:         tt.fields.Body,
                TemplateFile: tt.fields.TemplateFile,
                TemplateData: tt.fields.TemplateData,
            }
            if err := email.SendMail(tt.args.pluginInput); (err != nil) != tt.wantErr {
                log.Print(err)
                t.Errorf("Email.SendMail() error = %v, wantErr %v", err, tt.wantErr)
            }
        })
    }

    err = <-errCh
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("server error: %v", err)
    }
}
```

**After running unit test it is giving "EOF" error.**

I'm not very sure about mock server, because it is not having switches where based on client request it sends response.

Answer (score 0):

It happened because your implementation doesn't know, when it should close active connection.

Take a look on `smtpmock` package: https://github.com/mocktools/go-smtp-mock. This mock server is already designed for your case or even more :)

Comment: Thank you. Replying after one year, now I have changed company, that problem is left in older company. So right now I'll not be able to test it.